# Apache CSV parser with duplicate column headers

Tags: csv, apache-commons

I need to process CSV files which have duplicate headers, each data is in three columns (min, max and avg), but the header is the same for each column. The first column is min, second is average, third is max.

Apache CSV parser throws :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The header contains a duplicate name:
```

How can I configure the parser to accept duplicate headers ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no pre-defined configuration parameter in `CSVParser` that controls whether duplicate column names are acceptable.

A look at the source code shows that the `initializeHeader` method creates a `Map` which will have column names as keys and column indices as values. If you want to use header mappings, the column names must be unique.

However, there is a solution:

Specify a `CSVFormat` that ignores the column names defined on the first row of the CSV file, and [define your column names manually](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Defining_a_header_manually).

From the [`CSVFormat` documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html):

> **Defining column names**
>
> To define the column names you want to use to access records, write:
>
> ```
> CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader("Col1", "Col2", "Col3");
> ```
>
> Calling `withHeader(String...)` let's you use the given names to address values in a `CSVRecord`, and assumes that your CSV source does not contain a first record that also defines column names. If it does, then you are overriding this metadata with your names and you should skip the first record by calling `withSkipHeaderRecord(boolean)` with `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Can now configure CSVParser to allow duplicate headers.

```java
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.withAllowDuplicateHeaderNames()
```

Comment: This method is now deprecated, at least as of 1.9.0. The solution is to use [the CSVFormat Builder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.Builder.html#setAllowDuplicateHeaderNames-boolean-) @miha-hribar, do you want to update your answer? Would be good to also know what the resulting behavior is.